# Installing Oracle 12c on CentOs 6.4

Tags: centos-6, oracle-linux

I need to install Oracle DB 12c on Centos 6.5/6.4 that has no GUI (or xserver) installed,
Is there a way to do it?
Can you point me to a manual?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, actually. First you edit `../response/db_install.rsp` file to define your desired settings and then you run `./runInstaller -silent [-waitforcompletion] -responseFile ../response/db_install.rsp`. On the first look it may seem like a lot of editing but for plain install only a few parameters need to be changed. This is the best way how to make different unattended installs.

edit: Here's a chapter of Install guide with complex description for work with response files, which is default unattended deployment solution for OUI:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/install.121/e17720/app_nonint.htm#LADBI7831

Comment: Thanks!!
Do you have an example of a "default" response file, or can you specify the exact parameters that are needed?

Comment: Don't like reading, are we? ;-) It really depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want to install sw AND deploy new instance in one run?

Comment: :) it just after hours of struggling with this file...
Yes, I do want to configure and run an instance.
Just a simple single instance with no extra features

Comment: Hi..The best will be if you go through graphical installation process on different server (having X) and set everything you want. On the very last screen, just before hitting install, you have a choice to save response file of choices you just made. Then you can use the file anytime.

Comment: Or, if you check the file, every line is extensively commented, I'm sure you'd be able to find your way around.